# How to find apache server is running or not from another apache server?

Tags: java, ajax, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have two apache server. one apache server is running. another apache is not running.From running apche , how to find second apache is running or not? i want jsp code..

Comment: What do you mean by "check if an apache server is running"?  Is the process up?  Is it responding to requests?  Is it reachable from another particular server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't get your point, maybe you want to connect apache server through socket.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" import="java.io.*, java.net.*" %>

<% 
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("another.apache.com", 80);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

            socketOut.print("GET /index.html\n\n");
            socketOut.flush();

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e){}
%>
```

if there is not any exception, your another apache server is running, otherwise it's offline.

Comment: Thank You scy. You gave my expected answer.